# Not able to get the session_id in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using

```
$session= $this->session->userdata();
print_r($session);
```

I get the below

```
Array
(
   [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1439379995
)
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: @TillRohrmann, no extra context needed. CI3 has an updated doc page, specifying that the session keys have changed

Comment: @AlexTartan, great to hear :-)

Comment: `$this->session->session_id` does the trick

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

> Accessing session metadata
>   In previous CodeIgniter versions, the session data array included 4 items by default: ‘session_id’, ‘ip_address’, ‘user_agent’, ‘last_activity’.
>
> This was due to the specifics of how sessions worked, but is now no longer necessary with our new implementation. However, it may happen that your application relied on these values, so here are alternative methods of accessing them:

```
session_id: session_id()
ip_address: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
user_agent: $this->input->user_agent() (unused by sessions)
last_activity: Depends on the storage, no straightforward way. Sorry!
```

So, to get the session_id, just call `session_id()`

Comment: But how do i get the session_id

Comment: `$session_id = session_id();`